# Storing date as BigInt on sql server - is this a good idea?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, bigint

Okay now let me give an example

date : `15.12.2012 00:16:39`

Now this will be stored as

```
20121215001639
```

Now for example if i want to retrieve rows older than 30 min (30*60=1800 sec)

I can do just as

```
where date<20121215001639+1800
```

So would this be a performance way instead of storing as date time ?

Comment: If it's a date - store it as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` - why bother trying to store it as something that it's not?? What's the benefit?? Also see: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: adding 1800 will not give you 30 min in this format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fully agree with marc_s's comment above, but I decided to make a test, just for fun.

I created two tables, one with a `datetime` column and one with a `bigint` column, representing the same data.

Here is the sql fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74976/3

I've run this query for 500, 1000 and 5000 records and every time noticed that the execution plans are identical, so from a performance point of view there's no gain in using `bigint`.

However, there are obvious downsides for the `bigint` approach; some of them:

- the conversion to/from `bigint` requires more code to be written
- operations like filtering by month require more complex/less readable queries
- looking at the result grid in Management Studio, you cannot "parse"/interpret the results as quickly as you could if you saw the separated date parts.

Comment: thanks for comment. are there any site that shows how to use date type on sql server with a lot of examples ? i want to keep all date times as GMT time

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I think it's enough to check out the Transact SQL [documentation on datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.105).aspx) and the [date and time functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: also, for storing UTC/GMT values make sure you use `getutcdate()` instead of `getdate()`

Comment: if you encounter any other problems, post a question on SO and we'll be glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks, I was about to go down the bad path before reading this and thinking about all of the issues.  I wanted to use bigint because that would support dates from year 0000 to 9999, so a larger range, and down to the millisecond in time, and still give me some extra bits to kludge for things like "no date" or "no time" (i.e.-could set hours to "25" for "no time").  After more thought, not worth the extra work for the small savings.

Comment: I really hate it when i fall on a `BIGINT` date in a database... what where they thinking ?!?!?!? It takes more time to understand, more code to display dates, you can't read the date directly in the database... all that to accomplish almost nothing more than what a datetime would. Whoever read this... don't use bigint for date, please, it's a nigthmare